# Transform unicode character to its string representation

Tags: windows, excel, vba, unicode, ms-word

In VBA 6 is there any function (the fastest please) that can do something like this:

```
correspondentString = function(\uXYZP)
```

and give you the string representation of that unicode character?

Comment: Use the ChrW() function.

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this:

```
Dim LResult As String

LResult = StrConv(text, vbFromUnicode)
```

see here for more info:  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/strconv.php

Comment: thx for the response. it came too late. I didn't get the chance to test it. it was for a project I had. thx a lot !